# DropDownListFor using List of Class

Tags: vb.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I cant seem to get my HTML.DropDownListFor() to work properly with my structures.

**CategoriesEditViewModel**

```
Public Class CategoriesEditViewModel
    Public Property Categories As List(Of cihCategoryOrgDef)
    Public Property Category As cihCategoryOrgDef
    Public Property lists As cihLists = New cihLists()

    Public Property SelectedItem As String

    Public Sub New(catId as Guid)
     SelectedItem = codId.ToString
     lists.loadClubWaivers(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**cihLists**

```
   Private orgWaiverList As List(of cihWaiver)

   Public Sub loadClubWaivers(orgId as Guid)
    'Go to database and populate orgWaiverList
   End Sub

 Public ReadOnly Property organizationClubWaivers() As List(Of cihWaiver)
        Get
            Return orgWaiverList
        End Get
    End Property
```

**cihWaiver**

```
Public Class cihWaiver
    Public waiverId As Guid = Guid.Empty
    Public waiverName As String = ""
    Public waiverText As String = ""
End Class
```

**Edit View Page**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.SelectedItem, New SelectList(Model.lists.organizationClubWaivers, "waiverId", "waiverText", Model.lists.organizationClubWaivers))
```

The error i get is `'Library.cihWaiver' does not contain a property with the name 'waiverId'.`

but the cihWaiver class clearly has an item for 'waiverId'. I haven't done MVC stuff in a while, so maybe i'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was as simple as changing my **cihWaiver** Class to this:

```
Public Class cihWaiver
    Public Property waiverId As Guid = Guid.Empty
    Public Property waiverName As String = ""
    Public waiverText As String = ""
End Class
```

cane someone explain to me why the keyword `Property` is so important?

Comment: Because properties are better code design and should be used in place of public fields. The reason it wasn't working with fields is because of the Reflection that takes place when getting/setting values. It is only looking for properties and not fields.

Comment: As @TyCobb wrote a Property is **different** than a field.  It isn't just syntax.  Here's more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx